# OutOfMemoryException Exception while building Sitecore solution in docker

Tags: docker

I am running msbuild command in docker to build my solution but getting below error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error : Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException. [C:\build\src\Foundation\Test.Foundation.LanguageResolver\Test.Foundation.LanguageResolver.csproj]`

I tried increasing memory limit of solution image and cm image(see beloe code) but
Any idea how to fix this?

```
solution:
    mem_limit: 10GB
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-solution:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${SOLUTION_BASE_IMAGE}
        BUILD_IMAGE: ${SOLUTION_BUILD_IMAGE}
        BUILD_CONFIGURATION: ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION}
    scale: 0ver.csproj]
```

Comment: If you remove the language resolver test project does it build? Just wonder if bad test with infinite loop or something?

Comment: Does the issue still happen if you try to build a simple boilerplate solution?